# why loop set do end when set to false althoght I the it suppused to be true

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, loops, boolean

Hi I'm a noob C# programmer and I need some help here
I'm trying TryParse function and here is my code:

```
while (bContinue)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            // string numInput = Console.ReadLine();

            int num = 0;

             bool success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num);


            if (success)

            {
                bContinue = false;
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou have entered " + num + "\n       Salam");
                
            }
            else

                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");

        }
```

this code working perfectly fine but I tried to do it in another way:

```
   bool success = true;
        while (success == true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            // string numInput = Console.ReadLine();

            int num = 0;

            success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num);


            if (success)

            {
                

                Console.WriteLine("\nYou have entered " + num);
                success = false;
            }
            else

                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
            
        }
```

in the first code the loop end when entering valid number but in the second code the the reverse is happening the loop end when enter invalid number which is word. Also, in  the second code the VS is saying that "success = false;" is redundent and it is suggesting to remove it.

Any idea?

Comment: With a loop you have to be able to enter the loop when code starts and then exit later.  So second code you set success true to eneter loop and then false to exist.  The preference if you exit on true or false is up to programmer.

Comment: You have set `success = false;` in the **successful** path of the code, which will end up terminating the loop. And no, in its current form that statement is not redundant, are you sure you're showing the right version of the code? My guess is that "success" is the wrong word for this variable, as what you're probably trying to convey here is "keep asking for a number until a valid number is input".

Comment: If the input is not a number, after calling `TryParse` the `success` will be `false` then the while loop will terminate. You should initialize success to false, modify the Boolean expression to `success == false` and remove `success = false;` in if statement.

Answer (score 1):

> In the first code the loop end when entering valid number but in the second code the the reverse is happening the loop end when enter invalid number which is word.

In the second loop, the `success` variable is set to `false`, no matter the outcome of `TryParse`, which causes the loop to terminate when it receives any value, valid or not.

Assuming that you're trying to make the loop continue until a valid value is entered, your first loop should work, but if you want simpler code, you should try this:

```
bool success;
do {
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    success = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int num);
    if (success) Console.WriteLine($"You have entered {num}.");
    else Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
} while (!success);
```

> Also, in the second code the VS is saying that "success = false;" is redundent and it is suggesting to remove it.

`success = false` shouldn't be redundant and I agree with Lasse's comment above; I put the code into Visual Studio and IntelliSense didn't say anything about it (besides not needing to assign a value to `num`, etc.)